# iframe's contentDocument body is null

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am using the following iframe related code for uploading the file.

```
  function createAttachmentRequest(form, action_url, div_id){           
            document.getElementById("CreateAttachmentForm").elements["userId"].value = m_userID;
            document.getElementById("CreateAttachmentForm").elements["password"].value = m_password_e;
            document.getElementById("CreateAttachmentForm").elements["METHOD"].value = "POST";
            document.getElementById("CreateAttachmentForm").elements["parentIds"].value = strIssueID;

              // Create the iframe...
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");   
            iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");
            iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
            iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");

            // Add to document...
            form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
            window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";

            iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");

            // Add event...
            var eventHandler = function () {

                if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
                else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

                // Message from server...
                if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
                    content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
                } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
                    content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
                } else if (iframeId.document) {
                    content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
                }               

                if( content.indexOf('HTTP Status') !== -1){
                    document.getElementById("IssueFileUploadHead").innerHTML = 'There is an error. Please contact Administrator';   
                }else{
                    //get the response string and return the object id from the response string
                    document.getElementById("IssueFileUploadHead").innerHTML = content;
                    var responseString = document.getElementById("IssueFileUploadHead").innerText;
                    document.getElementById("IssueFileUploadHead").innerHTML = "Uploading...";
                    var responseTag = "<response>";
                    var responseEnd = "</response>";
                    var objId = responseString.match(new RegExp(responseTag + "(.*)" + responseEnd));

                    if(objId && objId.length>1){
                        window.parent.ModalHelper.setRetVal(objId[1]);
                    }
                    window.parent.ModalHelper.close();
                }

                // Del the iframe...
                setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 250);
            };

            if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
            if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

            // Set properties of form...
            form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
            form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
            form.setAttribute("method", "post");
            form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
            form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");

            // Submit the form...
            form.submit();
            document.getElementById("IssueFileUploadHead").innerHTML = "Uploading...";
        }
```

After getting the response from rest service,`iframeId.contentDocument.body` is becoming null. It appears that `iframeId.contentDocument` doesn't have the body. Any clue on what's wrong here and what can be done to make it work?
Now I have added the entire function to the question. Please take a look now.

Comment: Is the iframe loading from the same domain as your page? If not, this won't work for cross-domain security reasons.

Comment: I don't see any `src` for this iframe

Comment: @peeebeee iframe is loading from the same domain.

Comment: @charlietfl, I didn't get you, Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Ashok.N he or she meant that `src` source for `iframe` is not shown in your code. Btw,  how this piece of code works? `if (iframeId.contentDocument) {` ?

Comment: @Tim ggwp `iframeId.contentDocument` contains the document (response). My problem is that the body in that document is becoming null

Comment: If you aren't setting  `src` that may be part of the problem. How is content being loaded? Or how to you intend to use this iframe?

Comment: @Ashok.N the question is here where you loading the iframe content from or how?

Comment: @Tim ggwp,  Now I have added the entire function to the question. Please take a look now and let me know if you need any information.

Comment: @Tim ggwp, I am just passing the `form` , `url`, `div id` to the above javascript function and displaying the iframe.

Comment: @charlietfl No src attribute is NOT a problem. Every iframe has a contentDocument and a contentWindow at any point it is inserted into the dom. These values should never be null while the iframe is inserted into the dom.